# how to place YAML inside a YAML document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I am working with Rails fixtures for testing my rails application.  It is all good except one of my database columns is supposed to hold YAML content.  But, I am sure how to put the YAML markup I want to load into my database inside the YAML file.  Here is an example:

```
mvnforum:
    name: mvnforum
    abstraction_type: SVN
    url: src: test username: admin #is this possible?
    sourcepath: mvnforum/src/
    webroot:
    codesecure_project: mvnforum
```

If it is impossible to have YAML inside a YAML file what would be the best why to load this into a database for testing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to put YAML code inside a YAML document, you need to treat it like a string:

```
url: "src: test username: admin"
```

If you need a multiline string, you can do

```
mvnforum:
   name: mvnforum
   abstraction_type: SVN
   url: "
src: test\n
username: admin\n
"
   sourcepath: mvnforum/src/
   webroot:
   codesecure_project: mvnforum
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into using the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) to replace your fixtures for your tests and use something like [Factory Girl](http://textmode.at/2008/6/12/factory-girl-rails-fixture-replacement).

Take a look at this [great article on why you should use a factory over fixtures](http://www.dcmanges.com/blog/38) and the benefits.